# Adding a "%" at the end of a print statement

Tags: python

I am having an an issue. One of my assignments is to make a program that inputs 3 test scores and get the average, and the average should follow a "%" sign immediately after. I am not quite sure where to add the "%" sign in the print statement. I have combed through my book and cannot find anything.

```
keep_going = "y"

while keep_going == "y":

    test_1 = int(input(" Enter a test score: "))
    test_2 = int(input(" Enter a test score: "))
    test_3 = int(input(" Enter a test score: "))

    score = (test_1 + test_2 + test_3) / 3.0

    print(" Score ", format(score, ".3f",), sep="")

    keep_going = input(" Would you like to continue? (Enter y for yes)")
```

Comment: You are overthinking this, The best way is to `print("Score {:.3f}%".format(score))`

Comment: See https://pyformat.info/ for more about string formatting

Comment: _"I am not quite sure where to add the "%" sign in the print statement."_ I have a suggestion. When you're not quite sure about something, take a guess and see if it works. One of the great things about programming is that it's quite difficult to permanently damage anything just by playing around.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
print(" Score ", format(score, ".3f",) + "%")
```